# int[][] cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, int

```
System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
int row = sc.nextInt();
int[][] twod = new int[row][];
for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
{
  int p = i+1;
  System.out.println("Enter number of columns for row number "+p);
  int column = sc.nextInt();
  twod[row][column] = new int[row][column];
  for(int k = 0; k < column;k++)
  {
     int wat = k+1;
     System.out.println("Enter element in row number "+p+" and column number "+ wat );
     twod[i][k] = sc.nextInt();
  }
}

for(int men = 0; men < twod.length; men++)
{
  for (int women = 0; women < twod[men].length; women++)
  {
    System.out.print(twod[men][women]);
  }
}
```

When i try to run the program, it gives

> incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int
>         twod[row][column] = new int[row][column];

But i've already declared `twod` as an `int[][]`. Then why is the error showing up?

Comment: What should the line `twod[row][column] = new int[row][column];` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do with the statement
`twod[row][column] = new int[row][column];` is essentially assigning the element at indexes `[row][column]` a new `int[row][column]`. This does not work since the type of all elements in your `twod` object is `int` and not `int[][]`.

Comment: read the 3rd line of his code. his problem is that he wants to assign the position `twod[row][column]` a **new** 2d array and not single int

Comment: @XtremeBaumer just added a comment to that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
twod[i] = new int[column];
```